# Google Maps en Flutter: el mapa está en blanco!

Tags: google-maps, flutter

soy nuevo en Flutter y ahora estoy aprendiendo a cómo implementar Google Maps en mi aplicación. Para hacerlo estoy siguiendo esta guía oficial: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/google-maps-in-flutter/#0

El problema es que cuando inicio la aplicación como podéis ver no aparece el mapa aunque si aparece la firma de Google abajo a la izquierda y los botones de zoom.

[image: ScreenShot]

Llevo horas con esto y no encuentro el problema, he seguido los pasos de la guía estrictamente. Tengo mi API_KEY creada con las SDK de Google Maps para Android i iOS habilitadas.

**Este es mi main.dart**:

```
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  GoogleMapController mapController;

  final LatLng _center = const LatLng(45.521563, -122.677433);

  void _onMapCreated(GoogleMapController controller) {
    mapController = controller;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Maps Sample App'),
          backgroundColor: Colors.green[700],
        ),
        body: GoogleMap(
          onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
          initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
            target: _center,
            zoom: 11.0,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Estas son las dependencias de Google Maps agregadas a pubspec.yaml** :

```
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.3
  google_maps_flutter: ^0.5.11
```

**Mi AndroidManifest.xml** :

```
    package="com.example.google_maps_codelab">

    <application
        android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
        android:label="google_maps_codelab"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">

            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />

            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
              android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyC9ocbJyX8D921AwBOwv1dPEeiYv5xxxxx"/>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

**Mi AppDelegate.swift** :

```
import Flutter
import GoogleMaps

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    GMSServices.provideAPIKey("AIzaSyC9ocbJyX8D921AwBOwv1dPEeiYv5xxxxx")
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
}
```

**Mi Info.plist** :

```
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>io.flutter.embedded_views_preview</key>
    <true/>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>$(DEVELOPMENT_LANGUAGE)</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>google_maps_codelab</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NUMBER)</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
    <string>Main</string>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
    <false/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

**Y finalmente, esto es lo que aparece en la consola cuando inicio la app**:

```
√ Built build\app\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk.
I/Choreographer(24225): Skipped 75 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
D/EGL_emulation(24225): eglMakeCurrent: 0xaa288ac0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa7965b90)
D/EGL_emulation(24225): eglMakeCurrent: 0xaa288d60: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa7965790)
D/        (24225): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x93978b80, tid 24239
I/zzbz    (24225): Making Creator dynamically
W/zygote  (24225): Unsupported class loader
W/zygote  (24225): Skipping duplicate class check due to unsupported classloader
I/DynamiteModule(24225): Considering local module com.google.android.gms.maps_dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.maps_dynamite:221
I/DynamiteModule(24225): Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.maps_dynamite, version >= 221
V/DynamiteModule(24225): Dynamite loader version >= 2, using loadModule2NoCrashUtils
D/        (24225): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xa79269c0, tid 24237
W/zygote  (24225): Unsupported class loader
W/zygote  (24225): Skipping duplicate class check due to unsupported classloader
I/Google Maps Android API(24225): Google Play services client version: 12451000
I/Google Maps Android API(24225): Google Play services package version: 17785022
I/zygote  (24225): Do partial code cache collection, code=29KB, data=26KB
I/zygote  (24225): After code cache collection, code=29KB, data=26KB
I/zygote  (24225): Increasing code cache capacity to 128KB
I/zygote  (24225): Background concurrent copying GC freed 13492(1958KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 50% free, 1838KB/3MB, paused 2.139ms total 124.002ms
E/GoogleMapController(24225): Cannot enable MyLocation layer as location permissions are not granted
D/        (24225): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x931f5e80, tid 24291
D/EGL_emulation(24225): eglCreateContext: 0x931f11c0: maj 1 min 0 rcv 1
D/EGL_emulation(24225): eglMakeCurrent: 0xaa288ac0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa7965b90)
D/EGL_emulation(24225): eglMakeCurrent: 0x931f11c0: ver 1 0 (tinfo 0x931fc140)
D/EGL_emulation(24225): eglMakeCurrent: 0xaa288ac0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa7965b90)
D/EGL_emulation(24225): eglMakeCurrent: 0xaa288ac0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa7965b90)
D/EGL_emulation(24225): eglMakeCurrent: 0xaa288ac0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa7965b90)
W/DynamiteModule(24225): Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates not found.
I/DynamiteModule(24225): Considering local module com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:4
I/DynamiteModule(24225): Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates, version >= 4
W/zygote  (24225): Unsupported class loader
W/zygote  (24225): Skipping duplicate class check due to unsupported classloader
I/zygote  (24225): Do partial code cache collection, code=51KB, data=55KB
I/zygote  (24225): After code cache collection, code=51KB, data=55KB
I/zygote  (24225): Increasing code cache capacity to 256KB
```

Comment: Intentaste detener la app por completo , desinstalarla y volver a correrla? Puede que un proceso haya quedado colgado en segundo plano.

Comment: Veo que pruebas en emulador @ArnauAlloza, revisa si dentro del emulador puedes cargar el navegador chrome, esto aseguraría que el problema no es debido a internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo solucioné. Era un problema del emulador, que no tenía conexión a internet.

Answer (score 0):

Usando tu código veo que funciona sin problemas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Creo que deteniendo la app por completo y volviendo a instalarla va a funciona correctamente.

Cualquier cosa podes cambiar el código por este otro (pero el tuyo es igualmente funcional)

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {

  Completer<GoogleMapController> _mapController = Completer();
  final LatLng _center = const LatLng(45.521563, -122.677433);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Maps Sample App'),
          backgroundColor: Colors.green[700],
        ),
        body: GoogleMap(
          onMapCreated:(mapController) {
               _mapController.complete(mapController);
            },
          initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
            target: _center,
            zoom: 11.0,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: He probado de iniciar l'app en un dispositivo real y no en un emulador. Y funciona. Sabes qué puede estar pasando para que no funcione en el emulador?

Comment: Creo que en el emulador tenes que desinstalar la app por completo y volver a instalarla nuevamente para que vuelva a funcionar. No anda muy bien igualmente en el emulador por lo que ví.

Answer (score 0):

Asegúrate **tener habilitado Google Map** SDK para Android e IOS.

1. Vaya a [Google Developers Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/).
2. Elija el proyecto en el que desea habilitar Google Maps.
3. Seleccione el menú de navegación y luego seleccione "Google Maps".
4. Seleccione "API" en el menú de Google Maps.

   - Para habilitar Google Maps para Android, seleccione "Maps SDK for Android" en la sección "Additional APIs", luego seleccione "ENABLE".
   - Para habilitar Google Maps para iOS, seleccione "SDK de Maps para iOS" en la sección "Additional APIs", luego seleccione "ENABLE".

Para mas información Google Map posee una [guía](https://developers.google.com/maps/gmp-get-started) paso a paso (ingles).